# Non-scalar enumeration in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, colors, enumeration

Is it possible to have enumeration member that are non-scalar?

For example, how can I enumerate colors such that each color is a 1x3 double (as needed for plots), without using methods?

With the following class definition

```
classdef color
    properties
        R, G, B
    end
    methods
        function c = color(r, g, b)
            c.R = r;
            c.G = g;
            c.B = b;
        end
        function g = get(c)
            g = [c.R, c.G, c.B];
        end
    end
    enumeration
        red (1, 0, 0)
        green (0, 1, 0)
    end
end
```

I can write `color.green.get()` to get `[0 1 0]`, but I would like the same result with `color.green` to make the code cleaner.

A different solution may be setting `color` as a global struct, but it's not practical because global variables can cause confusion and I have to write `global color;` in each script/function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here, but I think the main answer is that you're currently doing basically the right thing (although I'd suggest a few small changes).

You can certainly have non-scalar arrays of enumeration values - using your class, for example, you could create `mycolors = [color.red, color.green]`. You can also have an enumeration with non-scalar properties, such as the following:

```
classdef color2
    properties
        RGB
    end
    methods
        function c = color2(r, g, b)
            c.RGB = [r,g,b];
        end
    end
    enumeration
        red (1, 0, 0)
        green (0, 1, 0)
    end
end
```

and then you could just say `color2.red.RGB` and you'd get `[1,0,0]`.

But I'm guessing that neither of those are really what you want. The thing that I imagine you're aiming for, and unfortunately what you explicitly **can't** do, is something like:

```
classdef color3 < double
    enumeration
        red ([1,0,0])
        green ([0,1,0])
    end
end
```

where you would then just type `color3.red` and you'd get `[1,0,0]`. You can't do that, because when an enumeration inherits from a built-in, it has to be a scalar.

Personally, I would do basically what you're doing, but instead of calling your method `get` I would call it `toRGB`, so you'd say `color.red.toRGB`, which feels quite natural (especially if you also give it some other methods like `toHSV` or `toHex` as well). I'd also modify it slightly, so that it could accept arrays of colors:

```
function rgb = toRGB(c)
        rgb = [[c.R]', [c.G]', [c.B]'];
end
```

That way you can pass in an array of `n` colors, and it will output an `n`-by-3 array of RGB values. For example, you could say `mycolors = [color.red, color.green]; mycolors.toRGB` and you'd get `[1,0,0;0,1,0]`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was hoping for the color3 solution... but your improvements to my example are really appreciated! Thanks!